# Can a webview in android access geo location?

Tags: android, html, webview, geolocation

According to my requirement in developing an applicaion we need to access the geo location of the user. We build a Html 5 based website and call that website URL in a webview to develop our mobile application. WIth the latest geo tags from HTML5 we can access the Geo location of the user in websites. can the same the Geo location be still accessed when calling from a web view?  Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to implement the location dialog functionality on your own using a `WebChromeClient`.  Here is a quick example:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient( new WebChromeClient() {

    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt( String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback ) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( context );

        builder.setMessage( origin + " would like to use your current location" );
        builder.setNegativeButton( "Don't Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) {

                callback.invoke( origin, false, false );
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        } );
        builder.setPositiveButton( "Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) {

                callback.invoke( origin, true, false );
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        } );
    };
} );
```

You can directly invoke `callback.invoke(origin, true, false )` if you don't want to display the permission dialog to your user.  I wouldn't recommend that though (as your website will be using the user's location without their consent).